# PowerShell: Create Hashtable with three columns

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashtable, psobject

Ultimately, I'm trying to create a script that will get all Windows Services Running as a domain Service Account from a list of remote machines and output a csv file with three columns: the Service Account Name, the Windows Service, and the Hostname. I cannot figure out how to create the hashtable with two arrays. I've had some success with just one key and one array using += but even that has some issues and I'm reading this is inefficient.

This is modified code that gets all Win Services running as System on my local system:

```
$server = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$tgtAcct = 'SYSTEM'
$reportCsv = Join-Path -Path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")) -ChildPath ("report.$(Get-Date -Format `"yyyMMdd_hhmmss`").csv")

$GetServiceAccounts = {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    $hostname
  )
  
  $serviceList = @( Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $hostname -Property Name, StartName, SystemName -ErrorAction Stop )
  $serviceList
}

Function Process-CompletedJobs(){
  
  $jobs = Get-Job -State Completed
  ForEach ($job in $jobs) {
    $data = Receive-Job $job
    Remove-Job $job
    
    If ($data.GetType() -eq [System.Object[]]) {
      $serviceList = $data | Where-Object { $_.StartName -ne $null -and $_.StartName.ToUpper().Contains($tgtAcct) }
      ForEach ($service in $serviceList) {
        $account = $service.StartName
        $winService = $service.Name
        $occurance = $service.SystemName
      }
    }
  }
}

Start-Job -ScriptBlock $GetServiceAccounts -Name "read_$($server)" -ArgumentList $server | Wait-Job > $null
Process-CompletedJobs
```

Here is what I've tried that isn't working:

```
$server = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$tgtAcct = 'SYSTEM'
$serviceAccounts = @{}
$accountTable = @()
$winSvcTable = @()
$occurTable = @()
$reportCsv = Join-Path -Path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")) -ChildPath ("report.$(Get-Date -Format `"yyyMMdd_hhmmss`").csv")

$GetServiceAccounts = {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    $hostname
  )
  
  $serviceList = @( Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $hostname -Property Name, StartName, SystemName -ErrorAction Stop )
  $serviceList
}

Function Process-CompletedJobs(){
  
  $jobs = Get-Job -State Completed
  ForEach ($job in $jobs) {
    $data = Receive-Job $job
    Remove-Job $job
    
    If ($data.GetType() -eq [System.Object[]]) {
      $serviceList = $data | Where-Object { $_.StartName -ne $null -and $_.StartName.ToUpper().Contains($tgtAcct) }
      ForEach ($service in $serviceList) {
        $account = $service.StartName
        $winService = $service.Name
        $occurance = $service.SystemName
        $script:serviceAccounts.Item($account) += $winService
        $script:serviceAccounts.Item($account) += $occurance
      }
    }
  }
}

Start-Job -ScriptBlock $GetServiceAccounts -Name "read_$($server)" -ArgumentList $server | Wait-Job > $null
Process-CompletedJobs

ForEach ($serviceAccount in $serviceAccounts.Keys) {
  ForEach ($occurance in $serviceAccounts.Item($serviceAccount)) {
    ForEach ($winService in $serviceAccounts.Item($serviceAccount)) {
      $row = New-Object PSObject
      Add-Member -InputObject $row -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Account" -Value $serviceAccount
      Add-Member -InputObject $row -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Service" -Value $winService
      Add-Member -InputObject $row -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Hostname" -Value $occurance
      $accountTable  += $row
    }
  }
}
$accountTable | Export-Csv $reportCsv
```

I'm trying to modify code written by Andrea Fortuna that almost does what I want but want to split the second column into two. Again, I'm also looking for how to do this without adding to each array using += if possible. https://www.andreafortuna.org/2020/03/25/windows-service-accounts-enumeration-using-powershell/

Comment: I'm not following what you expect the output to look like, is it this `$serviceList | Select-Object StartName,SystemName,Name`? In addition, if you care about efficiency, `Start-Job` is definitely not the way.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon : The output I'm looking for is a table with the account name, service name, and hostname. Also, I do care about efficiency and am always looking to learn better more efficient ways of doing things. Why is Start-Job inefficient and what would you do instead?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to export to CSV, then a single top-level hashtable is *not* the data structure you want.

`Export-Csv` will expect a *collection* of *individual objects*, so that's what you'll want to create:

```
Function Process-CompletedJobs(){
  
  $jobs = Get-Job -State Completed
  ForEach ($job in $jobs) {
    $data = Receive-Job $job
    Remove-Job $job
    
    If ($data.GetType() -eq [System.Object[]]) {
      $serviceList = $data | Where-Object { $_.StartName -ne $null -and $_.StartName.ToUpper().Contains($tgtAcct) }
      ForEach ($service in $serviceList) {
        # don't assign this new object to anything - let it "bubble up" as output instead
        [pscustomobject]@{
          Account = $service.StartName
          Service = $service.Name
          Occurrence = $service.SystemName
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock $GetServiceAccounts -Name "read_$($server)" -ArgumentList $server | Wait-Job > $null
Process-CompletedJobs |Export-Csv ...
```

Comment: I can't believe how difficult I was making this. This is so straight forward and easy. Thank you!

Comment: @ToToRoYN happy to have shown you some light, you're welcome! If my answer solves your problem, consider marking it "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left (or accept one of the other answers if they're a better fit) :)

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
$server = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$tgtAcct = 'SYSTEM'
$reportCsv = Join-Path -Path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")) -ChildPath ("report.$(Get-Date -Format `"yyyMMdd_hhmmss`").csv")

$GetServiceAccounts = {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    $hostname
  )
  
  $serviceList = @( Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $hostname -Property Name, StartName, SystemName -ErrorAction Stop )
  $serviceList
}

Function Process-CompletedJobs(){
  
  $jobs = Get-Job -State Completed
  $hashtable = @{}
  ForEach ($job in $jobs) {
    $data = Receive-Job $job
    Remove-Job $job
    
    If ($data.GetType() -eq [System.Object[]]) {
      $serviceList = $data | Where-Object { $_.StartName -ne $null -and $_.StartName.ToUpper().Contains($tgtAcct) }
      ForEach ($service in $serviceList) {
        $account = $service.StartName
        $winService = $service.Name
        $occurance = $service.SystemName
        $hashtable[$account] = @{winService = $winService; occurance = $occurance}
      }
    }
  }
  return $hashtable
}

Start-Job -ScriptBlock $GetServiceAccounts -Name "read_$($server)" -ArgumentList $server | Wait-Job > $null
$myHashTable = Process-CompletedJobs
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple it will work, this is the complete script and I have tried and valid for many servers you can change the variable `$hostnames  =  $env:COMPUTERNAME,host2,host3,..` as you need
and I added some parameters to get a grid view of result to test and add force and notypeinfo. in export-csv

Here is the code - I hope you mark it answer if it helps:

```
$hostnames  =  $env:COMPUTERNAME
$tgtAcct = 'SYSTEM'
$reportCsv = Join-Path -Path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")) -ChildPath ("report.$(Get-Date -Format `"yyyMMdd_hhmmss`").csv")

$TableName = "System Accounts"
#Create a table
$Table = new-object System.Data.DataTable "$TableName"

#Create a column and you can increase it as many as you need 
$col1 = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn "Service Account Name",([string])
$col2 = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn "Windows Service",([string])
$col3 = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn "Hostname",([string])

# Add the Columns

$Table.columns.add($col1)
$Table.columns.add($col2)
$Table.columns.add($col3)


  foreach($hostname in $hostnames){
    $serviceList =  Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $hostname -Property Name, StartName, SystemName -ErrorAction Stop | Where-Object { $_.StartName -ne $null -and $_.StartName.ToUpper().Contains($tgtAcct) }
    foreach ($service in $serviceList){
      $Row = $Table.NewRow()
      $Row."Hostname" =  $hostname
      $Row."Service Account Name" = $service.StartName
      $servicename = $service.Name.ToString()
      $Row."Windows Service" = $servicename 
    $Table.Rows.Add($Row)
    }}

$Table  | Out-GridView 
$Table  | Export-Csv $reportCsv -Force -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I like this solution, thank you for the input. I do have an issue, the Grid View generates as expected but the csv file is empty. Any ideas?

Comment: You are correct , make it in a separate line as follows
    $Table  | Out-GridView 

    $Table  | Export-Csv $reportCsv -Force -NoTypeInformation